# is there a way to use yahoo finance API in php

Tags: php, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I want to show actually a change of stock exchanges from yahoo, like in left top of the page, Dow  0.62% Nasdaq  0.54% in the below mentioned url

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=API
```

I want to collect top 10 stock exchange rates. I saw their API documentation [here](https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/sampleYahooManagedFinance) but that is for `C#`, is there a way to use the API & call that data in PHP, also tried to find from the solution but no such good luck:(

**I got a solution of it by using a http://quandl.com

Comment: Should be able to use `cURL` or `file_get_contents` to access most APIs... Also, the link you posted is just a search for api on yahoo finance...

Comment: If you've found how to call it in C#, then please hyperlink to that in your question, so we don't have to search for it as well. Ditto the API docs for Yahoo Finance, if you would. Are you wanting help finding a specific API, or are you just wanting to know how to apply a particular one? It might also be a good idea to search for "Yahoo Dow Nasdaq API PHP" to see how to use it, since many people will have done it before.

Comment: @brbcoding yup i tried that way but it calls the whole data..i need actually the API information so i can show the data in my way..

actually on yahoo page they show only two stock exchanges, i want to show actually more than two

Comment: @halfer actually i dont want only those i want the US all exchanges data:(
ok i am edition my query, thanks for guidelines

Comment: That link is a start, but people won't load up zip files from here, since they are a pain to unpack and browse. Make it easy for your readers (e.g. [this link](https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/sampleYahooManagedFinance)).

Answer (score 2):

Your link is wrong, but Yahoo! provides APIs that return CSV, XML and JSON- all of which are easy to work with in PHP.

https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/YahooFinanceAPIs

Comment: thanks for guiding me, let me do in this way:)

Comment: I'm still looking for the docs on json or xml on this link... I must be missing it somewhere...

Comment: @brbcoding yup there is no doc for JSON???

i think it quite easy to do with JSON but dont find the documentation too

Comment: @brbcoding i got this..i think this is some thing good to guide..

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys